# How to retrieve data from simple Cloud Firestore structure

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve simple data from Cloud firestore database.
With the following code, i'm trying to show 2 attributes from the collection "prodotti", but the toast message doesn't appear and neither the log message doesn't show up. Please can someone find the problem?
(the project it's at his starting point, don't blame me for the public rules, but i'm trying to understand how the basics works)

This is the database structure:

[Database structure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHkRu.png)

Fragment where i try to read those data:

```
public class FragmentHome extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View fragmentHomeView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_home_vuoto, container, false);
        return fragmentHomeView;
    }

    //debug message
    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "debug", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        DatabaseReference root= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final DatabaseReference prodotti= root.child("prodotti");
        final TextView nulla=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textCarrelloVuoto);
        ImageView carr=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.immagineCarrelloVuoto);
        ValueEventListener vel=new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String line="";
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String nome=ds.child("nome").getValue(String.class);
                    String ndisp=ds.child("ndisp").getValue(String.class);
                    line.concat(nome+" "+ndisp);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), line, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                Log.i("TAG", line);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        prodotti.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(vel);

    }

}
```

The "Prodotti" class:

```
public class Prodotti {

    public int id;
    public String nome;
    public boolean disponibile;
    public int ndisp;

    public Prodotti(){
        //chiamate da dataSnapshot
    }

    public Prodotti(int fid, String fnome, boolean fdisp, int fndisp){
        this.id=fid;
        this.nome=fnome;
        this.ndisp=fndisp;
        this.disponibile=fdisp;
    }

}
```

Comment: Good question, the tag and title state google-cloud-firestore, but FirebaseDatabase.getInstance() is for RTDB.

Comment: Your toast should also be next to the Log.i(...) rather than inside the for(...) loop.

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot. Beside that, please also add what is the query that you are using. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @Kato it's cloud firestore

Comment: @AlexMamo i changed the db structure as requested, i'm sorry it wasn't clear before. For the query, from all the tutorial i've seen that's all the code for retrieving data that seems i needed, therefore there isn't other code.

Comment: In that case you have to change your code because your code currently is for the realtime database instead of firestore. Take a look at the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

Answer (score 0):

This code is not accessing Cloud Firestore.  It's accessing Realtime Database.  The screenshot shows Cloud Firestore, but the code will never see that data because it's a whole different database product.

Please use the [documentation for Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) to learn how to work with it.